# Click on list, and extract data to sheet

Tags: excel, url, button, extract, vba

I am trying to get Excel, via VBA, to go to the webpage:

http://www.nordea.dk/wemapp/currency/dk/valutaKurser?0

Then click on the "12 måneder", from the drop down to the top right and download the table.

I got the copy/and paste nailed down, by use of querytable, but I can't get Excel to click on the button  - such that I get the correct period.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you get if you ask MS Excel to write the VBA code for you (using the recorder):

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www.nordea.dk/wemapp/currency/dk/valutaKurser?0", Destination:= _
    Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "valutaKurser?0"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Not sure if you can change something in a web query but you can certainly do so if you do it manually: (1) open the website, (2) change the option, and (3) then iterate through the items to get their values.

```
Sub GetRates()
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    WebSite = "http://www.nordea.dk/wemapp/currency/dk/valutaKurser?0"
    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate WebSite
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set Element = .document.all("fwRate")
        Element.Value = 4                       '=12 måneder

        'iterarte through the elements to get the rates manually

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer my question - it does not select the right element from the list.